# XML-RPC returning value before executing all function code

Tags: python, multithreading, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, simplexmlrpcserver

I have XML-RPC server:

```
import time

import xmlrpclib
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

class Worker(object):
    def start_work(self):
        # is it possible do return value to client here?
        self.do_work()
        return 'we started!'

    def do_work(self):
        while(True):
            print 'I\'m doing work...'
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 8080
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", port))
    print "Listening on port %s..." % port

    w = Worker()

    server.register_function(w.start_work)
    while(1):
        server.handle_request()

# vim: filetype=python syntax=python expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 encoding=utf8
```

And easy client:

```
import xmlrpclib
c = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8080/')
print c.start_work()
```

Of course value returned by start_work function will be never printed.

My question is how to rewrite server code to make possible returning value before finishing work. I know that I can use threads for that but I want to be sure that there is no easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want XML-RPC with long-running, early returning tasks, you probably need to rewrite your server into an asynchronous framework, like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with that. The documentation of twisted is really big and I can't find example of that. Could you please provide one?

Comment: basically, you would follow the examples linked, but to do more work after the return, you would do something to the effect of `twisted.internet.reactor.callLater(more_work_callback)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a good idea to do such a thing without threads or without reimplement some parts of the SimpleXMLRPCServer or without breaking XMLRPC protocol, however you can get an early answer by using a `yield` statement in your called method :

```
class Worker(object):
    def start_work(self):
        # is it possible do return value to client here?
        # yes, with a yield
        yield "the_return_value"
        self.do_work()
        # but yielding a first value and returning it to client will disable any next response
        # return 'we started!'

    def do_work(self):
        while(True):
            print 'I\'m doing work...'
            time.sleep(3)
```

And overriding the do_POST method of the `SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler` to call twice the called method (everything around the ### parts are the standard part of python code)

```
class MySimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        """Handles the HTTP POST request.
        Attempts to interpret all HTTP POST requests as XML-RPC calls,
        which are forwarded to the server's _dispatch method for handling.
        """
        # Check that the path is legal
        if not self.is_rpc_path_valid():
            self.report_404()
            return

        try:
            # Get arguments by reading body of request.
            # We read this in chunks to avoid straining
            # socket.read(); around the 10 or 15Mb mark, some platforms
            # begin to have problems (bug #792570).
            max_chunk_size = 10*1024*1024
            size_remaining = int(self.headers["content-length"])
            L = []
            while size_remaining:
                chunk_size = min(size_remaining, max_chunk_size)
                L.append(self.rfile.read(chunk_size))
                size_remaining -= len(L[-1])
            data = ''.join(L)

            # In previous versions of SimpleXMLRPCServer, _dispatch
            # could be overridden in this class, instead of in
            # SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher. To maintain backwards compatibility,
            # check to see if a subclass implements _dispatch and dispatch
            # using that method if present.
            response = self.server._marshaled_dispatch(
                    data, getattr(self, '_dispatch', None)
                )
            ##############################################
            ##############################################
            ## Here you'll have the first part of your response
            response = response.next() # to get the first item of the generator (yes, a little bit uggly)
            ##############################################
            ##############################################
        except Exception, e: # This should only happen if the module is buggy
            # internal error, report as HTTP server error
            self.send_response(500)

            # Send information about the exception if requested
            if hasattr(self.server, '_send_traceback_header') and \
                    self.server._send_traceback_header:
                self.send_header("X-exception", str(e))
                self.send_header("X-traceback", traceback.format_exc())

            self.end_headers()
        else:
            # got a valid XML RPC response
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/xml")
            self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(response)))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(response)

            # shut down the connection
            self.wfile.flush()
            self.connection.shutdown(1)

            ##############################################
            ##############################################
            ## Here you've send the the first part of your response to the client, relaunch the method
            self.server._marshaled_dispatch(
                    data, getattr(self, '_dispatch', None)
            )
            ##############################################
            ##############################################
```

Then, the main will become :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 8080
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", port), requestHandler=MySimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler)
    print "Listening on port %s..." % port

    w = Worker()

    server.register_function(w.start_work)
    while(1):
        server.handle_request()
```

Comment: It looks like yield can't work with xmlrpc: xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:cannot marshal <type 'generator'> objects">

Comment: @Adam : oh, yes, yield returns a generator object, try to use a `response = response.next()` call on the first response object.

Comment: I'm not sure what thats mean... could you please show some example?

Comment: Chances are that if your application is targeted for enterprise use, then as it matures you will find that this doesn't quite cover your needs.  Just use Twisted.  It isn't a huge complicated framework that you have to study for weeks in order to start using.  It is approachable.