# yield or log from a remote function in python SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, yield, simplexmlrpcserver

I am trying to call a long (time-consuming) function through XMLRPC in Python.

My server.py:

```
import time
import SocketServer
import SimpleXMLRPCServer

PORT = 19989

class MyXMLRPCServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass

def hello():
    for x in xrange(10):
        yield "hello {}".format(x)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = MyXMLRPCServer(("", PORT),
                            requestHandler=SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler,
                            logRequests=True,
                            allow_none=True)
    server.register_function(hello)
    server.serve_forever()
```

and my client.py:

```
import xmlrpclib

HOST, PORT = "localhost",   19989

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://{}:{}'.format(HOST, PORT))
    print my_server.hello()
```

Is there a way to see the progress of the `hello()` function (e.g. logging) on the client side before it is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106422/1431750) on SO, trying to achieve the same effect. Quoting its [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111176/1431750):

> If you want XML-RPC with long-running, early returning tasks, you probably need to rewrite your server into an asynchronous framework, like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html)

The [2nd answer from that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109658/1431750) shows a way to implement `yield` correctly in the XMLRPCServer. Esp since your current code gives the error: `xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:cannot marshal <type 'generator'> objects">`.

Comment: Overriding the `do_POST` method gives the error `'str' object has no attribute 'next'` on the server and `xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for localhost:19989/RPC2: 500 Internal Server Error>` on the client. Also, I posted a separate question, because, if I understood the similar question correctly, the author wanted to yield one string before running the function. I wanted to yield an unspecified number of strings, while the function runs.

Comment: `yeild` turns your function into a generator. So you require one more function which iterates over what `hello` returns. You also need to restructure your client and server code similarly. Note the use of `while(1): server.handle_request()` instead of `server.serve_forever()`.